# Is there a way to group a "key-value store data" by ID in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

Is there a way to group a "key-value store data" by ID in a multidimensional array?

SQL Tables:

```
Table 1: App
ID | Name      | Release
1  | TinyWings | 2014
2  | WarCraft  | 2012
3  | StarCraft | 1998

Table 2: AppInfo
ID | Key       | Value
1  | Genre     | Casual
1  | Rating    | 0+
1  | System    | iOS
...
2  | Genre     | RTS
2  | Rating    | 6+
2  | System    | Win
...
3  | Genre     | RTS
3  | Rating    | 12+
3  | System    | Win
...
```

For the profil php page of the App i use

```
$app = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

but on the index.php page, i need an array something like this for pagination:

```
Array (
    [0]=> Array (
              [Genre]=>[Casual]
              [Rating]=>[0+]
              [System]=>[iOS]
              ...)
    [1]=> Array (
              [Genre]=>[RTS]
              [Rating]=>[6+]
              [System]=>[Win]
              ...)
    [2]=> Array (
              [Genre]=>[RTS]
              [Rating]=>[12+]
              [System]=>[Win]
              ...)
)
```

the only way i have found is to use

```
MAX(CASE WHEN ... THEN .. END) AS ...
```

for EVERY KEY in the prepare statement to write the rows into columns, is there a way to use it with PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR or an better and easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but really you should restructure your table into one which uses your keys as column names as it would make your life easier.

You can get the data the way you want with the following query, but it's a bit clumsy:

```
select a.id, a.value as 'genre', b.value as 'rating', c.value as 'system'
from Table1 a, Table1 b, Table1 c
where (a.key = 'genre' AND b.key = 'rating' and c.key = 'system') AND (a.id = b.id AND b.id = c.id)
group by a.id
```

Heres a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eedb74/22/0)